# Java: DrawImage from array

Tags: java

I am new to java and i am having alot of problems trying to display images into my program.
I have placed the images in the proper map and have placed them into a array:

```
    private Image[] images;
    images = new Image[9];
    images[0] = new ImageIcon("images/hang1.png").getImage();
    images[1] = new ImageIcon("images/hang2.png").getImage();
    images[2] = new ImageIcon("images/hang3.png").getImage();
```

The next part i cannot manage to get the image displayed at all. I have tried multiple options without success.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int count = 0;

        g.drawImage(images[count], 50, 50, ImageObserver );
        count++;
}
```

Any solution to this would be very welcome!
Kind Regards.

Comment: Why you have 3 images. Your code will paint ever the first image.

Answer (score 0):

as the comment says, I'm assuming that you want to paint all of them simultaneously on the screen  at the same time, you are painting them all in the same place, so only one of the images will be displayed.

if you want to do this, you need to change the coordinates for the last 3 images so that are they are in a different place.

if you are still having problems, try rendering just one of the images and satisfy
yourself that it works fine. then work up trhough the array

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing custom painting?

Add the Icons to a JLabel and add the label to your panel which uses an appropriate LayoutManager. The images will be painted automatically.

Read the JLabel API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Labels" for examples with Icons.